# Como puedo capturar texto ingresado en un editText y mandarlo a otra activity2 en otro editText

Tags: android-intent, activity, edittext

Estoy haciendo un login y un formulario de registro por si la persona no tiene cuenta.

Necesito que la persona se registre y al darle en el botón registrar se lanza la activity con los datos de usuario y contraseña que fueron ingresados en el registro, para poder compararlos con los que ingrese el usuario lógicamente si no son correctos se muestre un toas. El caso es que no me funciona cuando le mando esos dos parámetros a la actividad de login.  open app again agradezco que me puedan asesorar para que me funcione. gracias

Actividad 2 Registro.java

```
package com.example.santiagovalencia.candidaturaybalance;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RegistroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected EditText Et_Nombre,Et_Apellidos,Et_Usuario,Et_Password,Et_Cedula,Et_Edad,Et_Correo;
    protected Button B_Registrar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

        Et_Nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Nombre);
        Et_Apellidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Apellidos);
        Et_Usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Usuario);
        Et_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);
        Et_Cedula = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Cedula);
        Et_Edad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Edad);
        Et_Correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_E_mail);
        B_Registrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Registrar);

        B_Registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LogginActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("NOMBRE",Et_Nombre.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("APELLIDOS",Et_Apellidos.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("USUARIO",Et_Usuario.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("PASSWORD",Et_Password.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("CEDULA",Et_Cedula.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("EDAD",Et_Edad.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("CORREO",Et_Correo.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Actividad 1 login.java

```
package com.example.santiagovalencia.candidaturaybalance;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected TextView Tv_IrRegistro;
    protected EditText Et_UsuarioL,Et_PasswordL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loggin);

        Et_UsuarioL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Usuario);
        Et_PasswordL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Contraseña);
        Tv_IrRegistro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_Registro);

        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            String usuario = extras.getString("USUARIO");
            String passwoord = extras.getString("PASSWORD");

            Et_UsuarioL.setText(usuario);
            Et_PasswordL.setText(passwoord);
        }



        Tv_IrRegistro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegistroActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Santiago, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En el mundo de la informática escribir todo un texto en mayúsculas ha sido siempre muy mal visto. Recomiendo que te tomes unos minutos a normalizar tu pregunta, escribiéndola con el debido uso de mayúsculas/minúsculas según corresponda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No sé por qué recurres a <s>`Bundle`</s> para obtener los datos.

Tienes que encontrar el `Intent` que inició la actividad, y buscar en él los datos.

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null){
        String usuario   =  (intent.hasExtra("USUARIO")  != null) ? intent.getStringExtra("USUARIO")  : "";
        String passwoord =  (intent.hasExtra("PASSWORD") != null) ? intent.getStringExtra("PASSWORD") : "";

        Et_UsuarioL.setText(usuario);
        Et_PasswordL.setText(passwoord);
    }
```

Comment: Hola que tal amigo,muchas gracias por tu aporte, aun me genera el mismo bug al darle registrar.

Comment: @SantiagoValencia prueba de la nueva manera, he usado un operador ternario para verificar que el `Intent` tenga esos extra realmente. También, puedes cambiar esto: `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LogginActivity.class);`  por esto: `Intent i = new Intent(this,LogginActivity.class);` donde creas el `Intent` y le pones los extra. Si no funciona, agradezco que comentes si te da algún error o algo.

Comment: Al estar llamando a la hora de crear el intent, dentro de una clase anónima en el onClick, deberá llamar al contexto de esta manera `Intent i = new Intent(RegistroActivity.this, LogginActivity.class);` Con el nombre de la clase donde nos encontramos, seguido del punto y this.

Comment: @A. Cedano ejecuta pero aun no funciona el boton registrar muy bien. error terminal : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.santiagovalencia.candidaturaybalance.RegistroActivity$1.onClick(RegistroActivity.java:35)

Comment: @DiegoLoL no es una clase anónima, el dato pasa de la clase `RegistroActivity` a la clase `LogginActivity`. Yo lo uso de la forma explicada y me funciona bien. Santiago, el error que comentas se refiere a otra cosa, al parecer estás referenciando mal tu `EditText`. Ahora reviso.

Comment: @SantiagoValencia el nuevo error se refiere a los `EditText` de los que intentas recoger los datos para pasarlos en el `Intent`.  Dice que uno o más de ellos son nulos. Creo que deberías revisar que todos los `EditText` de `RegistroActivity` existen en el layout `activity_registro` y que tienen los id indicados en el código. Si quieres, coloca en la pregunta el contenido de `activity_registro.xml`.

Comment: Si utilizas solo el this dentro del View.OnClickListener, no reconocerá ese this, pero seguramente tenga ese error en otro lado.

Comment: Me parece que sí lo reconocería @DiegoLoL, pero es cuestión de probar y si no funciona, entonces habría que hacerlo como has dicho en tu comentario de más arriba.

Comment: @A. Cedano tenias razón amigo había colocado el mismo id de la actividad de login. muchas gracias.

Comment: Como puedo enviar esa informacíon a la actividad 3 que es para mostrar toda la información, pero en este caso cuando de en el boton registrar se vaya y se almacene en los TextView de esa activity  3 sin necesidad que se abra dicha actividad.

Comment: @SantiagoValencia eso sería motivo de otra pregunta, sobre todo por la última parte que comentas: *... se vaya y se almacene en los TextView de esa activity 3 sin necesidad que se abra dicha actividad ...* Estaríamos entrando en otra temática totalmente distinta del planteamiento original. Este sitio existe para que las preguntas/respuestas sirvan a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema. No podemos por eso abordar más de un problema por pregunta. Sugiero que, si esta parte del problema se resolvió, des por solucionada esta pregunta y plantees una nueva con el otro problema.

Comment: @SantiagoValencia Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.